# JS dropdown Caret animation breaks input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a navagation bar that includes a dropdown. The dropdown has Javascript that changes caret orientation when the dropdown button is clicked. However when any space within the dropdown is clicked the dropdown collapses. I have a search bar within the dropdown and it cannot be used. How would I alter the javascript to only collapse and expand on clicking the button.

**Javascript**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown').click(function(e){
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').toggleClass('show');
    $($(e.target).find('.down-caret').toggleClass('open-caret'));
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(document).click(function(){
      $('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('show');
      $('.down-caret').removeClass('open-caret');
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think you can move the

```
$(document).click(function(){
    $('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('show');
    $('.down-caret').removeClass('open-caret');
});
```

part out of the  click listener for the dropdown. Otherwise you'll be attaching the listener each time the dropdown is opened. Also, if you only have one `.down-caret` on your page, you can simplify

```
$($(e.target).find('.down-caret').toggleClass('open-caret'));
```

to

```
$('.down-caret').toggleClass('open-caret'));
```

Then one thing you could try is to filter the listener for closing the dropdown

```
$(document).not('#search').click(function(){...}
```

Using however you identify your search bar. Another way would be to catch the click event for the search bar and stop the propagation

```
$('#search').click(function(){
    return false;
});
```

Taking that all into account, the modified code could look something like:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown').click(function(e){
    $('.dropdown-menu').addClass('show');
    $('.down-caret').addClass('open-caret');
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  $(document).not('#search').click(function(){
    $('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('show');
    $('.down-caret').removeClass('open-caret');
  });
});
</script>
```